# Cannot attach a document to email via mandrillapp JSON api

Tags: javascript, json, email, mandrill

I'm trying to send an email with attached document via mandrillapp JSON api `send-template` method by javascript, the email is successfully sent, even images can be attached to `images` array but the documents that is sent in `attachements` array with base64 content are not delivered. Here is the example of the request

url: `https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json`

POST data:

```
"key":"private key",
"message": {
  attachements: [
     {content: "dGVzdA0K", name: "test.txt", type: "text/plain"}
  ],
  images: [
     {content: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...", name: "img.png", type: "image/png"}
  ],
  ...
}
...
```

the message with the content and image is received but without text document. I failed in attempts to send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to a typo in the word "attachements" in the payload. it should be attachments.

Hope this helps,

Comment: It was a stupid mistake that took me almost a day, Thank you a lot!